# How to configure service log format?

Tags: systemd

I have a service, for example :

```
[Unit]
Description=My app
PartOf=myorg.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
User=myuser
NotifyAccess=main
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my_app
Restart=always
RestartSec=1s

[Install]
WantedBy=myorg.target
Alias=myapp.service
```

Its logs are visible in `journalctl`. One log example :

```
Feb 16 08:32:11 mycomputer-0013952a677a hapic[410613]: TheLogMessage
```

Format look like :

```
<date> <hostname> <logger name>[<thread id>]: <message>
```

How can I configure this format ? My goal is to add the service alias in log format.

Comment: That really depends on how the log messages get written in the first place... A fairly common is that you service generates standard output and systemd subsequently streams that output to journald, with each new line  marking a new entry. I think you should be able to set extra meta data in the journal message with the  setting [`LogExtraFields=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LogExtraFields=)  and https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For information, I found another solution : Add en var containing my service name with "Environment" parameter and use its value in my program to prefix my log messages.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/695505/change-systemd-unit-tag-send-to-journalctl-syslog